# Does anyone know the particle size of carbamate and protonated MEA?

Tags: organic-chemistry, ions

Does anyone know the particle size of carbamate and protonated MEA ?  that's the product when CO2 is absorbed into monoethanolamine (MEA)

Comment: There are no particles: everything stays in the solution.